# how do I get the result of a select within a function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I want to get a table with value 1 as result, but this query returns 0 rows. Why is this happening?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_6()
 RETURNS TABLE
            (
                r int
            )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
   execute 'SELECT 1 as r';
end;
$function$;

select test_6()
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `RETURN QUERY`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_6()
 RETURNS TABLE
            (
                r int
            )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
    execute 'SELECT 1 as r';
end;
$function$;
```

Also, as was suggested in comments bellow, you should use the function like a table `select * from test_6()`

And you can use just

```
RETURN QUERY
SELECT 1 as r;
```

Comment: And the function should be used like a table: `select * from test_6()`

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! and for the way to output a table with columns